# Mongoose.findOneAndUpdate() is not creating new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

The mongoose.findOneAndUpdate() method isn't creating new object when a new WEEKNUM is provided by the client. Instead it just updates the WEEKNUM and WEEKDATA that's already present in the collection. How can I fix that? What am I missing here?

**SCHEMA:**

```
{
    ageGroup:String,
    monthData: [{
    month:String,
    circleTimeWordsList:[String],
    circleTimeTips:[String],

    weekData : [{
        weekNum : String,
        theme   : String,

        dayData: [{
            day:String,
            circleTimeSong: String,
            circleTimeBook: String,
            circleTimeActivity: String,

            learningCenter: [{
                learningCenterName:String,
                learningCenterActivity:String 
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

This is my schema. I am using mongoose.findOneAndUpdate() for inserting/updating the data in the collection.

Eg.

1. If we have nothing in the collection. The data will be inserted.
2. If we have following data already in the collection.

   ```
   {
       ageGroup:"2",
       monthData: {
       month:"January",
       circleTimeWordsList:["word 1", "word 2"],
       circleTimeTips:["teaching tips", "teaching tips 2"],

       weekData : {
           weekNum : "1",
           theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 1",

           dayData: [{
               day:"Monday",
               circleTimeSong: "circleTimeSong 1", 
               circleTimeBook: "english 1", 
               circleTimeActivity: "circleTimeActivity 1", 

               learningCenter: [{
                   learningCenterName:"Art Center",
                   learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 1" 
               },
               {
                   learningCenterName:"Language Center",
                   learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 1"
               }]
           }]
       }
   }
   ```

   }

and if the client sends the following JSON to server,

```
{
        ageGroup:"2",
        monthData: {
        month:"January",
        circleTimeWordsList:["word 1", "word 2"],
        circleTimeTips:["teaching tips", "teaching tips 2"],

        weekData : {
            weekNum : "2",
            theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2",

            dayData: [{
                day:"Monday",
                circleTimeSong: "circleTimeSong 2", 
                circleTimeBook: "english 2", 
                circleTimeActivity: "circleTimeActivity 2", 

                learningCenter: [{
                    learningCenterName:"Art Center",
                    learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 2" 
                },
                {
                    learningCenterName:"Language Center",
                    learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 2"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

the mongodb collection will look like this:

```
{
        ageGroup:"2",
        monthData: {
        month:"January",
        circleTimeWordsList:["word 1", "word 2"],
        circleTimeTips:["teaching tips", "teaching tips 2"],

        weekData : [
                {
                    weekNum : "1",
                    theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 1",

                    dayData: [{
                        day:"Monday",
                        circleTimeSong: "circleTimeSong 1", 
                        circleTimeBook: "english 1", 
                        circleTimeActivity: "circleTimeActivity 1", 

                        learningCenter: [{
                            learningCenterName:"Art Center",
                            learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 1" 
                        },
                        {
                            learningCenterName:"Language Center",
                            learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 1"
                    }]
                },

                {
                    weekNum : "2",
                    theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2",

                    dayData: [{
                        day:"Monday",
                        circleTimeSong: "circleTimeSong 2", 
                        circleTimeBook: "english 2", 
                        circleTimeActivity: "circleTimeActivity 2", 

                        learningCenter: [{
                            learningCenterName:"Art Center",
                            learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 2" 
                        },
                        {
                            learningCenterName:"Language Center",
                            learningCenterActivity:"learningCenterActivity 2"
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However the current code just updates old data instead of create a separate object for weekNUM 2 in WEEKDATA array

This is the code I am using:

```
MyData.getMyDataModelObject().findOneAndUpdate({ageGroup:data.ageGroup, month:data.monthData.month/*, weekNum:data.monthData.weekData.weekNum*/}, data, {upsert:true}, function(err, foundData){});
```

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` updates the **entire** document. What you obviously want is to add or update a **sub**document. Read here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html. Probably it's worth re-designing your schema, if you need to perform those kind of updates often.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming request is coming in body

```
var data=req.body;
delete data.weekData;
findOneAndUpdate(query,data,function(err,model){
  if(err){
// handle here
    }
 model.monthData.weekData.push(req.body.weekData);
 model.save();
});
```

OR

```
var data=req.body;
    findOneAndUpdate(query,{$push:{"weekData":data.weekData},function(err,model){
      if(err){
    // handle here
        }      
    });
     delete data.weekData;
     findOneAndUpdate(query,data,function(err,model){

      });
```

OR

Use Subdocuments in mongoose in this u have to do changes in u r schema but it is better option if u r performing CRUD operations
link [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)